# Force vim to use en_gb as default dictionary

Tags: vim, latex

I'm trying to force vim to use `en_gb` as the default dictionary using my `vimrc`.

My goal is to have it at least for `tex` files.  This is how it is right now.

```
set spell spelllang=en_gb
```

vim, unfortunately, can not tell me if `color` and `colour`  is correct?

Comment: I just noticed this; `en_gb` in your code is correct; but `US_gb` in both your title and your text is nonsense. :P

Comment: nice catch! fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just testing those words as the only word in the document, neither is correct: they will both be marked as `SpellCap` (word not capitalized). If you put in `Colour` and `Color`, or if you put another word before them, `Colour` will not be marked, and `Color` will be marked as `SpellLocal` (wrong spelling for selected region). You can see this for yourself using these:

```
hi SpellBad ctermfg=red
hi SpellCap ctermfg=blue
hi SpellRare ctermfg=green
hi SpellLocal ctermfg=yellow
```

By default, on many colourschemes, all of those just render the same way (underline), so you can't distinguish them.

You might also find that out by using `z=` (suggest word) on `colour` - you'd get `Colour` as a top correction.

Comment: Then the question is, is there a way to force it to have use en_gb

Comment: `set spelllang=en_gb` in your `.vimrc`, if I understand what you're asking. And possibly `au FileType tex setlocal spell` (or you could put `setlocal spell` into your `~/.vim/after/tex.vim`).

Comment: let me try that